# Executor Service clear map values in multithreading environment

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

i have a situation here. I am using Executor Service for making use of multithreading. So now i am trying to add a value to a map and clear it for each thread as soon as i am done with that loop. I have wrote the below code for that.

I have created a map, and saving the value for each iteration and clearing it. But as i am using Executor Service its creating 10thread and adding the value to the map i believe. thats why i am able to see multiple values even i am just adding one value and clearing it.

So how do i clear the map each trasaction in the loop :(

Code:

```
public class Test1 {
public static void main(String[] args){
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    final Multimap<Object, Object> map = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(ArrayListMultimap.create());

    final List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
    listA.add("e");
    listA.add("f");
    listA.add("g");
    final List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
    listB.add("e");
    listB.add("f");
    listB.add("g");
    final List<String> listC = new ArrayList<String>();
    listC.add("e");
    listC.add("f");
    listC.add("g");


    for (final String stateId : listA) {
        for (final String gradeList : listB) {
            for (final String subjectList : listC) {
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                map.clear();
                map.put("f", "hi");
                System.out.println("map before "+map);

                System.out.println("map after "+map);
            }
        });
    }

    }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(24L, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

output:

```
map before {f=[hi, hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
 map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi, hi]}
map before {f=[hi, hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
 map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi, hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
 map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
 map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map before {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
map after {f=[hi]}
```

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: It behaves as it should.

Comment: But i want to clear the map at the end of the loop..so that i can save new value for new iteration in the loop and go on. Is there solution to this please? @Jerry06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple - the [javadoc](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html) clearly states:

> This class is not threadsafe when any concurrent operations update the multimap. Concurrent read operations will work correctly. To allow concurrent update operations, wrap your multimap with a call to Multimaps.synchronizedListMultimap(com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap).

In other words: you can't just take any convenient collection class and throw multiple threads at it - without further precautions.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how can i implement this for the above scenario. That would be a great help . I am just learning multithreading and i got the concept of what the javadoc mean..but not really sure how to implement it. not much google results for that as well.So can you please provide an example atleast? @GhostCat

Comment: i  tried this: final Multimap<Object, Object> map = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(ArrayListMultimap.create()); Now i see very few times the map contains two values. I ahve updated this in the question as well..Please correct me?

Comment: Please avoid getting into "more question" ping pong. When *this* question is sufficiently answered, you *should* consider opening a new question for the new problem. Anyway: I am wrapping up for today. So in case somebody else has a "more complete" answer, feel free to accept that answer. Otherwise, feel free to drop me a comment tomorrow, then I could have another look into your problem.